# get the directory path by inputing the filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file named test.apk this file in located in `C:\\workspace\app\build\output\apk\test.apk`
in node js i tried following code

```
var workDir = 'C:\\workspace\app'
    var path = require('path');


 var localTagPath = path.dirname(workDir);

 console.log(path.resolve(localTagPath, 'test.apk'))
```

what i need is to get the test.apk without specifyinh the path in code

```
 (var workDir = 'C:\\workspace\app\build\output\apk\test.apk')
```

instead of this  ihave to specify like this

where local path is

```
 var localpath = workDir +(\..+\..+\..\)+test.apk

 path.resolve(localTagPath, 'test.apk')
```

Comment: There is function relative http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use local file paths as browsers do not have access to the computer's filesystem.